# Mapquest schema URL for iphone

Tags: iphone, url, schema, mapquest

I try to build an iPhone app to launch Mapquest using schema URL. Does Mapquest expose schema URL for other apps?
If yes, can you provide document or example?

Comment: Add my vote to getting this question answered! The TeleNav GPS app supports a custom URL schema (telenav://....). Sure hope MapQuest can support a URL as well!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with it, but MapQuest does offer an API and has a (beta) URL builder:
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/quick_start

Answer (score 0):

The latest info I see is that they are working on it and have no release date.

See:  http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/389376#_19_message_421803